# jquery change class when sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```js
//JavaScript 

$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/

#sortable1, #sortable2 {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 142px;
  min-height: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!--My HTML -->

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

My question : 
When `li` element move from one `ul` to another `ul` at that time `li` contain class change.

exa. take `li` from first `ul` to move second `ul` at that time `li` class change `ui-state-default` to `ui-state-highlight`.

you can edit into js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fo51dggo/

Comment: I dont think your question is very clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a stop method in sortable. change class there

> stop  event is triggered when sorting has stopped.

Try like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.data('parentID', ui.item.parent().attr("id"));
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var parentID = ui.item.data('parentID');
            if (ui.item.hasClass("ui-state-default")) {
                if (parentID !== ui.item.parent().attr("id")) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("ui-state-default");
                    ui.item.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                }
            } else if (ui.item.hasClass("ui-state-highlight")) {
                if (parentID !== ui.item.parent().attr("id")) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
                    ui.item.addClass("ui-state-default");
                }
            }
            console.log(ui.item.parent().attr("id"));
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m1pukw80/)

Comment: This is only work for elem move from left to right but not work for elem move from right to left. see `http://jsfiddle.net/fo51dggo/2/`

Comment: I have second issue when you move element into same block at that time also class change but it's not good, i mean when element move into same block at that time class become not change.

Comment: can you tell me one more thing, i want store minimum one item of first block that is not move to second block. minimum one item store in first block. how can do this?

Comment: hey it's all item move from one block to another block :( . I don't want to move all item. first block store any one time that not move.

Comment: you wanna to keep one item at least in both block ? or only left block ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[`stop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop)** event to handle class changes,

```
start: function (event, ui) {
        $currParent = ui.item.parent();
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
    if(!ui.item.parent().is($currParent)) ui.item.attr('class', ui.item.siblings().attr('class'))
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fo51dggo/7/)**

`ui.item` is the jQuery object representing the current dragged element.

---

Full code :

```
$(function () {
    var $currParent;
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $currParent = ui.item.parent();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if(!ui.item.parent().is($currParent)) ui.item.attr('class', ui.item.siblings().attr('class'))
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

This would change `ui-state-default` to `ui-state-highlight` and vice-versa.

Comment: one issue when you move element into same block at that time also class change but it's not good, i mean when element move into same block at that time class become not change.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Updated my answer. There is a more efficient way though, using `ui.sender` Refer -http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop. But for some reason this is not supported in your jQuery UI version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `drop( event, ui )` that executes when you drop the droppable object. You can use:

```
ui.item.addClass("ui-state-highlight");
```

Inside the `drop( event, ui )` function. More info at [Droppable - Event Drop](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop).